# Computers in office freezing without eventlogs

Tags: freeze, desktop-computer, unresponsive

We’ve got an office building and most users got laptops. However, some developers got pcs, and this is where the issue happens.

A random number of pcs tends to freeze randomly and there’s not yet any cause found for this.
Eventlogs are empty, there’s no bsod.
The cursor remains visible on screen but everything becomes unresponsive.

A full reboot, by using the power switch, helps and gets the user back on track.

What are good ways to examine this issue? Any helpful tips?

Comment: A decent computer can run 24x7 for years without crashing. Is building power going out occasionally overnight?   Try putting desktops on small UPS units

Comment: Can you setup the computer to create an Active dump and configure the computer to crash on power button as per: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/forcing-a-system-crash-with-the-power-button - If that doesn't work, use the crash on ctrl scroll Microsoft article.  Once you have an active dump of the computer in the hung state, it is possible to debug that with WinDbg.  The preview version from the Store is fine.  Come back once you have the dump.  Thanks